# Django not deleting session id in mongoDB database when logging out

Tags: django, mongodb, api, djongo, cvat

I have integrated the MongoDB database with CVAT.
I get "Could not login" Error when I try to login **second time** into CVAT portal.
I get below error in browser console (full error screenshot attached)
"FAILED SQL: INSERT INTO "auth_user_groups" ("user_id", "group_id") VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s)"
I know that this is because django has not deleted the session id in database in auth_user_groups collection for first time login-logout.
How can I fix this issue and make sure I will be able login-logout multiple times without having to manually delete session id in mongoDB ,auth_user_groups collection.
[[image: browser console error in DB][1]]

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Django signal like this :**

*models.py* (you can put your script in another file of your choice)

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out


def delete_session_id(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    # Delete the Django session Id here

# Connect the function to user_logged_out signal
user_logged_out.connect(delete_session_id)
```